# How do I mark my terminal with special text if it is a production terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

I've got dev, production & staging environment sessions open on my terminal. Is there a way to modify the production env session so that it shows a nice big text overlay, and I don't end up pasting the wrong stuff in haste ever?

Comment: What terminal application are you using? Some allow you to change colors and to define "profiles" that have different looks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to modify your PS1 prompt.

```
export PS1='[Production] \u@\h \W $'
```

I think that is the only way you can do, unless you change the background for each environment in your terminal-emulator.

Comment: I've already got this, but the background idea sounds workable. Thanks :)